# Need to understand how to break up data into 2 separate lines on same graph

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

[image: screenshot]

I have data that looks like the above.

I have successfully graphed out the overall sum of suicides/100k population over the years with the following code:

```
df2 = df2[df2.year != 2016]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,7))
df2.groupby(['year'])['suicides/100k pop'].sum().plot(marker='o')
```

**But** I want a graph that also shows 2 different lines, one for male and one for female, over the same timeframe. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subset the data on sex before applying the groupby, then plot for each gender.  You can also change the marker (or any other option) during the iteration.

```
df2 = df2[df2.year != 2016]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,7))

genders = ('male', 'female')
markers = ('o', 'x')
colors = ('b', 'r')

for b, m, g in zip(colors, markers, genders):
    df2[df2.sex.eq(g)].groupby(['year'])['suicides/100k pop'].sum().plot(marker=m, ax=ax)
ax.legend(genders)
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you! As a follow-up, when I show the legend, both lines are called "suicides/100k pop". Is there a way to change that so the colors reflect the sexes?

Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, just pass a list/tuple of labels to `ax.legend`.  See the updated answer